# Why I have no results with a collection group query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using for first time collection groups querys on firestore in my web application but I can't retrive any data and I don't know why

I'm using Firebase SDK 7.6.1 and I have created the indexes correctly i think.
This is my Collection data structure:

[image: Firestore Collection Data Structure]

And this are my Indexes:

[image: Firestore Indexes]

And finally the code with I'm trying to retrieving data is:

```
  doc = this.database.collectionGroup('Authors')
  .where('Name','==',this.TextParams.trim().toLowerCase());
```

I expected to retrieve the documents where the author name is equal to my TextParams variable

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, Authors is not a subcollection, it's an array type field.  Since it's not a subcollection, a collection group query won't work at all.  Also, it's currently not possible to search among array field items.

What you will have to do is actually put your Authors into a subcollection.